# How do I inspect an integer's base-2 representation in Standard ML?

Tags: binary, sml

I am trying to implement a repeated squaring algorithm in SML. I want it to be tail recursive.

The goal is to multiply all x^k where k is 2^m and 2^m is a 1 in the binary representation of n.

E.g, for x^25, calculate x^1 * x^8 * x^16 because 16 + 8 + 1 = 25

I have no idea how to represent a number by it's binary parts, or to use bitwise operations to check manually (because from what I can tell SML has no bitwise operations).

I would prefer to use the out-of-the-box SML library, so no importing other libraries.

This is a homework problem, so if you can answer without completely giving it away that would be great.

Edit: I'm using SML of New Jersey.

Comment: While sml doesn't have any bitwise operators, the sml basis library does have a "basic type" that has functions which perform bitwise operations

Comment: could you show me where to look to find bitwise AND?

Comment: Sure, sorry if I was too vague before http://sml-family.org/Basis/word.html#SIG:WORD.andb:VAL

Comment: Thanks! If possible, could you give me an example on how to use andb? I've been trying it in the sml terminal but all the syntax possibilities i try do not work.

Comment: Mainly getting the andb is not defined error, do I need to import it from somewhere? edit: "unbound variable or constructor"

Comment: In smlnj this works for me: Word.andb(Word.fromInt(1), Word.fromInt(0)); you can always "open Word", to avoid having to prefix them with Word.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can finally write this program now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to matt, I found the solution.

Using the Word type from the SML basis library, I used:

Word.andb(Word.fromInt(x), Word.fromInt(y)) > Word.fromInt(0)

Comment: This is not an answer. You should remove it before the downvoters come along.

Comment: I added this because I wanted to mark it as resolved, but it seems I need to wait 2 days. I'll edit to to have the answer which solved my question.