# How to do bitwise AND in SML/NJ?

Tags: binary, sml, smlnj

Need it for a program I'm writing (repeated squaring to comput x^n). I can't seem to find the syntax for it, or if it is even supported.

Comment: I think my answer here already answers your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740771/how-do-i-inspect-an-integers-base-2-representation-in-standard-ml), so either delete that one, or edit it if there's something else you wanted there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're available within the [`Word8` and `Word` structures](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/word.html#SIG:WORD.andb:VAL).

```
let
  open Word8
  infix andb orb xorb notb << >> ~>>
in
  print (Word8.fmt StringCvt.BIN 0wxF)             (* 1111 *)
; print "\n"
; print (Word8.fmt StringCvt.BIN 0wxA)             (* 1010 *)
; print "\n"
; print (Word8.fmt StringCvt.BIN (0wxF andb 0wxA)) (* 1010 *)
; print "\n"
end
```

Comment: I want to note that there are also `andb orb xorb notb << ~>>` (though not `>>`) in the `IntInf` structure

Comment: The link is broken; [here's the updated link](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/word.html#SIG:WORD.andb:VAL)